# How can I evaluate my nonlinear model (without a model comparison)?

Tags: nonlinear-regression

I have a non-linear model that seems to work quite well. Compared to other similar models, using the same data it has significantly more negative AIC and BIC, so I'm quite confident that it is better than the other models. However, I'm inexperienced in nonlinear regression, and I don't really know how to evaluate the model on its own terms. In other words how do I make the case to someone that this is a 'good' model?

Comment: Define 'good', for your purposes. What aspects or features of a model are important?

Comment: Thanks,d Glen_b. I suppose that's my question.  For instance, in linear regression there are p-values and R-squared values.  In my model each parameter is 'significant,' but there I don't know of any way to describe how effective the model is other than AIC and BIC in comparison with other models.  Is there any way to evaluate this model other than comparisons.  Can I use the Log-Likelihood, perhaps?

Comment: I can't define your criteria for you. What aspects of a model make it better or worse for your purposes? (Note that when I do linear regression *neither* p-values nor $R^2$ necessarily suggest to me the difference between a good and a bad model. If you think they're useful criteria, we already have very different senses of what 'good' is. So for me to give useful answers to you, I'd need to know what you think *good* is in terms of your own situation - and preferably, why you think it's good, in order that I, or someone similar to me, might think of some alternatives.)

Comment: In this case there are 2 independent variables of interest.  One has 3 parameters associated with it and the other has 1.  Of particular interest to me are the specific values of 2 of the parameters.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: So in one sense, I'm interested in the specific values of two of the parameters, as well how much variation there is between the predicted values of the model and the data.

Comment: (i) The variation between the fit and the data (sums of squares of error) will be comparable if you have the same number of parameters in each model - as will MSE ($s^2$) or $s$ -- any of those seems very sensible. If the models are different nonlinear models, how are parameters comparable?

Comment: Ok, I'll see what I can do with sums of squares.  The models are similar, the results of different steps in stepwise model-building.

Comment: I'm concerned by what you might mean by stepwise model building there. But in any case it sounds like you'll be comparing models with different number of parameters, in which case SSE is *not* comparable.

Comment: Right, hence, the reason my initial question is how I can evaluate a model on its own terms, without comparison to other similar versions.

Comment: Fair enough - but then I'd point back to my first few comments. If parameter values are of interest, then having sufficiently small standard errors (/sufficiently narrow confidence intervals) might be an argument for 'good', but what really makes a model 'good' depends on what you want it to do.